# How can i set system.nullable of datetime as an optional parameter in a subroutine?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I tried the following, but i get the error

> constant expression is required

```
Public Sub ExampleSub(ByVal Test as string, 
  Optional ByVal fromDate As System.Nullable(Of DateTime) = Date.Today)
'A Great sub!
End sub
```

and here is the C#

```
public void ExampleSub(string Test, 
  System.Nullable<DateTime> fromDate = System.DateTime.Today)
{
    //A Great sub!
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the Greek equivalent.. Could be a "Subprocedure" also :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, the compiler tells you why :)

in C#:

```
public void ExampleSub(string Test)
{
    //A Great overload!
    ExampleSub(Test, System.DateTime.Now);
}

public void ExampleSub(string Test, System.Nullable<DateTime> fromDate)
{
    //A Great sub!
}
```

Now, IFF you know that `null` will not be legitimately by passed in by a caller, you could do:

```
public void ExampleSub(string Test, System.Nullable<DateTime> fromDate = null)
{
    fromDate = fromDate?? System.DateTime.Now;
    //An Even Greater sub!
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution (in Vb.NET) and now i get error BC31405: Optional parameters cannot have structure types. Any ideas please?

Comment: @Chocol8: mmm not sure. My sample was C#, and it sure compiles in C#: http://ideone.com/NJ4yk

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a non-constant expression for the default parameter. `System.DateTime.Today` will depend on when you run the program so it is not constant.

Use a constant expression for default and then check for that and set `fromDate` to `System.DateTime.Now` in the routine. Normally `null` would be used as the special value as in  @sehes answer. If `null` has another special meaning to your code you could use a value which will never be used as the defaul parameter, e.g. `System.DateTime.MinValue`:

```
public void ExampleSub(string Test, 
  System.Nullable<DateTime> fromDate = DateTime.MinValue)
{
    fromDate = fromDate == DateTime.MinValue ? System.DateTime.Now : fromDate;
    //A Great sub!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VB

```
Public Sub ExampleSub(Test As String, _
                      Optional fromDate As System.Nullable(Of DateTime) = Nothing)
    'A Great sub!
    If fromDate Is Nothing Then
        'code here for no fromDate
        'i.e. Now
        fromDate = DateTime.Now
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, the error is: Optional parameters cannot have structure types.

Comment: @openandfree - What release are you running?

Comment: I am using 3.5
Though I have solved it as: Optional ByVal TimeSlotDate As DateTime = Nothing

Answer (score 0):

If someone is doing this in VB.Net this is a way I solved my issue, I didn't find the exact thing on this thread, if it helps someone:

```
  /*I set below line as parameter in method*/
  Optional ByVal SlotDate As DateTime = Nothing

  If Not SlotDate = Nothing Then
       /* code to execute when date passed */
  Else
       /* code to execute when there is no date passed */
  End If
```